# Javascript Promise Anti-Pattern error

Tags: javascript, sqlite, promise

I am using Ionic 2 with SQLite. I am getting an error, and I suspect it is due to me not using Promises correctly.

I get the following error:

> ERROR REFRESHING CHATS: {}
>
> TypeError {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'executeSql'
> of undefined"}

**ts**

```
private database = new SQLite();

public openDatabase(): Promise<Array<Message>> {
    let promise: Promise<Array<Message>> = new Promise<Array<Message>>(resolve => {
        if (this.database) {
            let promiseChats: Promise<any> = this.refreshChats();
            let promiseMessages: Promise<any> = this.refreshMessages();
            Promise.all([promiseChats, promiseMessages]).then(() => { resolve(this.messages) });
        } else {
            this.database.openDatabase({
                name: "data.db",
                location: "default"
            }).then(() => {
                let promiseChats: Promise<any> = this.refreshChats();
                let promiseMessages: Promise<any> = this.refreshMessages();
                Promise.all([promiseChats, promiseMessages]).then(() => { resolve(this.messages) });
            }, (error) => {
                console.log("OPEN ERROR: ", error);
            });
        }
    });
    return promise;
}

public refreshChats(): Promise<any> {
    return this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM chats", [])
        .then((chatData) => {
            this.chats = [];
            if (chatData.rows.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < chatData.rows.length; i++) {
                    this.populateChat(chatData, i);
                }
            }
            return this.chats;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("ERROR REFRESHING CHATS: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

When I debug the code, and break on `this.database.executeSql`, `this.database` is not `undefined`. Also, you can see there is a check on `this.database` to see if it's `undefined` before too. Yet, the debugger steps out the `Promise` into the `error`, reporting the error shown.

Also, after the `Promise` finishes, the `this.chats` are populated. So I am very confused.

If anyone can suggest what I am doing incorrectly, I would appreciate it.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code as follows, but still get the same error:

```
public openDatabase(): Promise<Array<Message>> {
    let promise: Promise<Array<Message>> = new Promise<Array<Message>>(resolve => {
        if (this.database) {
            Promise.all([this.refreshChats(), this.refreshMessages()]).then(() => { resolve(this.messages) });
        } else {
            this.database.openDatabase({
                name: "data.db",
                location: "default"
            }).then(() => {
                Promise.all([this.refreshChats(), this.refreshMessages()]).then(() => { resolve(this.messages) });
            }, (error) => {
                console.log("OPEN ERROR: ", error);
            });
        }
    });
    return promise;
}

public refreshChats(): Promise<any> {
    return this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM chats", [])
        .then((chatData) => {
            let promises: Array<any> = [];
            this.chats = [];
            if (chatData.rows.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < chatData.rows.length; i++) {
                    promises.push(this.populateChat(chatData.rows.item(i)));
                }
            }
            Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                return this.chats;
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("ERROR REFRESHING CHATS: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: 1. It's possible that `this` in `populateChat()` is not the `this` you expect it to be.

Comment: 2. Code is confusing. `refreshChats()` loops through `chatData.rows` but in the loop calls `this.populateChat(chatData, i)`, which iteslf works on `chatData.rows.item(i)`. It would make more sense to call `this.populateChat(chatData.rows.item(i))`.

Comment: 3. You know that `this.database.executeSql()` is asynchronous because you have `this.database.executeSql(...).then()` in two places.  But (a) `populateChat()` doesn't return  a promise (as it should), and `refreshChats ()` treats `populateChat` as if it were synchronous (it needs to agggregate returned promises).

Comment: Please don't keep changing the question -  comments (like mine) and answers no longer relate to what is now being asked. By all means add, but don't overwrite.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, apologies for updating the code. I understand that.

Comment: Your code is not safe: you are not checking `this.database` after resolving the `openDatabase` promise. Your assumption that it is _never_ `undefined` is clearly wrong. The fact that your array is populated regardless suggests that the condition occurs at the end of the sequence. Did you set a conditional breakpoint on that line?

Answer (score 0):

You are employing a bit of a Promise antipattern which I will describe to you. Although I can't see a reason it would cause your problem, it may help with debugging.

It's known as the [explicit-construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) and essentially it is when you create a `new Promise` unnecessarily.

For instance in your code, both of your functions create a new Promise at the start, where they could instead just return the promise used later;

```
public refreshChats(): Promise<Array<Chat>> {
  if (!this.database || this.database === null) {
    console.log('ERROR refreshing chats: database = ' + this.database);
  }

  return this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM chats", [])
    .then((chatData) => {
      this.chats = [];
      if (chatData.rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chatData.rows.length; i++) {
           this.populateChat(chatData, i);
        }
      }
      return this.chats;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("ERROR REFRESHING CHATS: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

This may help to break up your error so that you can see where it originates. If you produce any further information, ping me and I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that does simplify the code too. I will give it a try.

Comment: I have modified my code as you suggested, I have updated the question above. I am still getting the same error. Do you think it may not be related to my `Promise` anti-pattern? Do you think it my be a `SQLite` issue?

Comment: @Richard can you update the question with the full error, with line numbers? That may help.